# Can I say that residuals are white noise?

Tags: time-series, self-study, econometrics, residuals, white-noise

[image]

I want to check whether residuals are white noise or not. When I look at the plot, all lags do not pass(exceed) the significance band except for fourth lag. However, fourth lag's p-value of 0.228 is higher than alpha 0.05. Can I say that residuals are white noise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really have a basis to assert that they *are* white noise.  Failure to reject the null is not the same thing as H0 actually being true

However, the evidence that they're something else is quite weak -- the values are reasonably consistent with white noise.

I think your interpretation of the p-value for the Q-statistic at the 4th lag is wrong. Take a [look](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljung%E2%80%93Box_test) at what the Q-statistic is actually doing; it's not looking "at the 4th lag" but at lags up to 4.